# Kivy/Python - calling function with 3 arguments without giving any

Tags: function, arguments, kivy

So here is some code from a book about Kivy. When a 'search' button is pressed search_location function  is called. In its UrlRequest there is a call to found_location function without any arguments. But found_location takes 2 arguments so how does it even work? Where is the 'request'? Shoudn't the call in UrlRequest look more like: self.found_location(sth,sth)?

```
class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):
    search_input = ObjectProperty()
    search_results = ObjectProperty()
    def search_location(self):
        search_template = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/" + "find?q={}&type=like"
        search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
        request = UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location)
    def found_location(self, request, data):
        data = json.loads(data.decode()) if not isinstance(data, dict) else data
        cities = ["{} ({})".format(d['name'], d['sys']['country']) for d in data['list']]
        self.search_results.item_strings = cities
```

If you could also explain what data['list'] is that would be awesome. When I look at the search_url link there is no 'list' inside.

Answer (score 2):

```
UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location)
```

This passes UrlRequest the two parameters, the second of which is the function itself. UrlRequest automatically calls that function with two arguments, specifically itself and the data it has retrieved.

> Shoudn't the call in UrlRequest look more like: self.found_location(sth,sth)

No. The point is that you *don't* want to call the function, only to pass the function itself to UrlRequest so it can call it later.

Comment: As I am currently reading the book myself, I wanted to give a short hint on the last part of the question. 'list' is a key from the dictionary returned by UrlRequest after parsing the json response from the openweathermap web service. Try : "print (data)" as the first line of the found_location() function and you should see 'list' somewhere in the beginning of the string.